# PyQt app won't run properly unless I open the whole folder

Tags: python

So I'm trying to share my PyQt project. When I download the zip file and extract it, it looks like

[image]

If I run `app.py` from CMD, it will run the app, but without the icon file which is inside of that folder. Inside of the code I do need that file and point to it, so I'm not sure why it doesn't find it automatically. It seems that without it the app doesn't work properly. I was wondering if there's a work around for this issue.

Here is how the app looks when I "open folder" in my IDE:

[image]

Here is how it looks when I simply open the `.py` file, in that same folder:

[image]

Anything related to the icons (basically all notifications) are not working when I run it like that.

I'm not sure what why it behaves like this, but I'd like to be able to share the code for anyone to use without them opening the whole folder.

Comment: Probably you are loading the icons using a relative path ?

Comment: @MauriceMeyer indeed. What is my alternative is currently I use this? `self.tray_icon = QSystemTrayIcon(QIcon('icon\icon.png'))`

Comment: @MauriceMeyer even using `os.path.abspath("icon\icons")` didn't yield new results if that's what you mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually, I ended up changing how I'm using the paths.

I added this

```py
dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)
iconFile = os.path.join(dirname, 'icon/icon.png')
```

So now I'm using `iconFile` as my path. Seems to fix the issue